# Adding a 'More fields' button to a file upload form field in a Drupal webform

Tags: jquery, drupal

I managed to add fields to submit attachments in a Drupal webform.

Now all I need is to restyle them to only allow one upload per charge plus a 'add more button'. I need to restyle the 1 into 2. Maybe a jquery solution would be enough.

How can this easily achieved?[image]

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first added programatically the 5 fields and then hide the first 4 them using the script below.

```
        /*Multiupload*/
        first = $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').first();
        first.after('<a id="addmore" href=#>'+Drupal.t("[+] Add more upload fields")+'</a>');
        $('.webform-client-form').find('div[id$="-ajax-wrapper"]').each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            first.show();
        });

        var c = 0;
        $('#addmore').bind('click', function(e) {
            var item = $('#edit-submitted-file'+ c +'-ajax-wrapper');

            item.show();
            ++c;
             if (c == 4) {
                $('#addmore').hide();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try **[Webform Add More](http://drupal.org/project/webform_addmore)** module. But I would recommand this module to you. I hope this will help you out.

Comment: I tried but with no dice. I found another solution: see below